# Список инициализации конструктора и инициализация массива

Tags: c++, список, конструктор, инициализация

Я бы хотел понять, как список инициализации конструктора работает с членами-массивами.

Допустим:

```
class Type
{
    public:
    Type() : data{}
    {}
    private:
    uint8_t data[1024];
};
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что `Type() : data{}` инициализирует все элементы массива `data` нулями?

Если это так, то возможно ли инициализировать все элементы члена-массива ненулевыми(одинаковыми) значениями в списке инициализации конструктора?

Вариант:

```
Type() : data{7}
{}
```

Приводит к тому, что инициализируется только первый элемент члена-массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В рамках концепции *униформной инициализации*, массивы в списке инициализации конструктора инициализируются так же, как и где-либо еще. Никаких особенностей у списка инициализации конструктора нет, кроме некоторых синтаксических отличий.

В стандартном С++ нет готового синтаксиса для инициализации всех элементов обычного массива одним и тем же [ненулевым] значением. Однако извернуться через шаблоны можно, например, вот так

```
class Type
{
public:
  Type() : Type(std::make_index_sequence<1024>())
    {}

private:
  template <std::size_t ...I> Type(std::index_sequence<I...>) : data{ (I, 7)... }
    {}

  int data[1024];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Фактически, данная конструкция инициализации

```
data{7}
```

эквивалентна конструкции вида

```
uint8_t data[1024] = { 7 };
```

Список инициализации содержит лишь один элемент, который используется для инициализации первого элемента массива. Все остальные элементы массива не имеют соответствующих инициализаторов, а потому будут инициализированы 0.